# Error com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None) while writing dataframe into excel binary notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a data frame into excel sheet(xlsb), which is having formulas, using xlwing library:

```
app = xw.App()

book = xw.Book('ABC.xlsb')

sheet = book.sheets('SL Dump')

sheet.range('A1').values=final_merge_dataframe
```

After running the above code, I am getting this error:

> com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

Comment: Please help me for the above problem.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. I recently uninstalled Office / Excel 2010 from my machine and I'm getting the error since then. I only have Office 365 on the computer now. Version 16.0.12872.20200 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have the same problem,

```
dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

After installing MS Office into my machine the error was resolved, it seems *xlwings* requires some packages or files from the MS Office to communicate with, although, I did not find anything referring to that on the documentation if someone could refer to that documentation it would be helpful.